# mysql changing values in table?

Tags: mysql

I have to change the values in my table and create an temporary table from that. But not with `UPDATE`, since I have to keep the original table.

for example a table like `Table(id, date)`, I have to create a temp table by changing the date values. The ones which are `NULL` must be `CURRENT_DATE()`.

How can I manage that??

Answer (score 0):

Create temporary table with (id,date)

then

```
INSERT INTO tempoaryTable (id,date)
SELECT id, IFNULL(date,CURRENT_DATE())
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [INSERT-SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) form to copy all values from original table to temporary, setting corresponding field to CURRENT_DATE().

Answer (score 0):

Syntax might be off as I don't now mysql

```
insert into temp_table
select id,coalesce(date,current_date) from mytable
```